# Error try to get a string representation of an instance through ipdb

Tags: python, pdb

I have this class:

```
class Point(PointAbstract):
    """
    Class used to expand shapely.geometry.Point functionality
    """

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s, %s' % (self.x, self.y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s, %s' % (self.x, self.y)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, %s' % (self.x, self.y)
```

When I try to evaluate an instance through ipdb I get:

```
> /home/...
    151         p = Point(float(each[4]), float(each[3]))
--> 152         for i, _each in enumerate(headers):
    153             if not _each in headers_to_ignore:

ipdb> p
*** SyntaxError: SyntaxError('unexpected EOF while parsing', ('<string>', 0, 0, ''))
```

I would expect something like:

```
123.0, 321.0
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does `p.x` or `p.y` have a useful result?  Which?

Comment: No, but it's because what Martijn Pieters said. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`p` is a `pdb` command to print values (short for `print`), and Python expects an argument to that command.

It is **not** interpreted as the name `p`. Use either:

```
ipdb> p p
```

to tell `p(rint)` to print the object `p`, or escape the reference:

```
ipdb> !p
```